# short / detailed buttons

Tags: html, css, button

How to implement two buttons, "short" and "detailed"? "short" should be the default and show one version of the page. Upon clicking the "detailed" button, another version of the page should be showed.

Since this is a bit difficult to explain, perhaps see the example below.

example page:

- never mind the contents
- requires javscript
- https://www.klimafakten.de/behauptungen/behauptung-aber-am-suedpol-nimmt-die-eismasse-zu
- Scroll down a bit.
- Check the buttons "Kurz" (stands for short) and "Ausführlich" (stands for detailed).

requirements:

- does not totally make content inaccessible without javascript (while noscript is activated)
- works in major modern browsers

ideally:

- works without javascript (while noscript is activated)

Comment: did provided answer worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use Css to achieve show hidden content. Css has a property called `display` that can be set to none or block. We can use focus to detect click on a element.Below is just a dummy example. You can try to achieve same.

CSS

`body { display: block;}
.span3:focus ~ .alert { display: none;}
.span2:focus ~ .alert { display: block;}
.alert{display:none;}`

HTML

`<span class="span3"  tabindex="0">Short</span>
<span class="span2"  tabindex="0">Detailed</span>
<p class="alert" >This is hidden</p>`

Please check the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nnodjtf2/

Comment: It's same as http://www.cssportal.com/css3-preview/demo/css-menu-ex1.html ? The problem with that is, once you clicked hide and then click somewhere else, the menu will expand again.